# getting 'attribute error while using tuple arguments python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, tuples

I am trying to "until(EC.visibility_of_element_located" function in my method.But getting error like this,what is the reason ?

```
by = (<selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="0df329cbca657f67360d8fa26fc0ca1c")>, ('xpath', "//div[@title='Kapat'])"))

    def _find_element(driver, by):
        """Looks up an element. Logs and re-raises ``WebDriverException``
        if thrown."""
        try:
>           return driver.find_element(*by)
E           AttributeError: 'BasePage' object has no attribute 'find_element'
```

Here is my code,BasePage.py::

```
def click(driver,*by_locator):
      
        WebDriverWait(driver, 60) .until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator)).click()
```

> and I am calling this function:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.trendyol.com/")
    driver.maximize_window()
    website_is_up_and_running("https://www.trendyol.com/")
    time.sleep(5)
    bp.click(driver, (By.XPATH,"//div[@title='Kapat'])"))
```

Comment: Update the question to include the entire traceback message.

Comment: And how did you create `driver`?

Comment: driver = <utilities.BasePage.BasePage object at 0x7f9f1ac50>
     by = (<selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="")>, ('xpath', "//div[@title='Kapat'])"))
     
      def _find_element(driver, by):
   a2c55e3d77a    """Looks up an element. Logs and re-raises ``WebDriverException``
       if thrown."""
       try:
     >           return driver.find_element(*by)
     E           AttributeError: 'BasePage' object has no attribute 'find_element'
     
     /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py:411: AttributeError

Comment: I'm not sure, but is correct to use the `*` in command `return driver.find_element(*by)`?

Comment: @Prophet I changed the method like this:\n                                                                   def click(driver,by_locator,locator_name):
     WebDriverWait(driver, 60) .until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator,locator_name)).click()                      
 but it gives this error:WebDriverWait(driver, 60) .until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator,locator_name)).click()
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Can you update the code in the question itself?
Also, I do not understand why to pass by_locator and locator_name? 2 parameters. Isn't it enough to send 1?